# Architecture event driven advice

Tags: java, spring, events, architecture, jms

Lately I have upgraded my application work in an event driven architecture using Spring3.1

I was wonder what do you think:

1. having a DAO instance in each class which has the need of inserting/updating/etc record in the DB.(regular way)
2. shall I send messages to DAO(via jms/channels/whatever) and the message's content will be the instructions of what I should do (inserting/updating/etc record in the DB)

how way number 2 is good in a loose coupling manners?

maybe it's overkill ?

this or any other suggestions or advice are welcome.

thanks.
ray.

Comment: 2 makes sense only if it really needs to be split into separate components and you have more than one modlue using DAO module or you have a clustered set of DAOs (and sharded databases) for performance reasons (rather unlikely scenario).

Comment: When you saying "you have more than one module using DAO module". to module you refer to a specific class or component in my project? because I do have couple of classes using the same DAO.

Comment: By module I mean a separate application. You are sending messages from A to B. If A and B are not separate applications why send message instead of method call? For loose copuling in single application DI container (Spring, Guice, CDI) is usually enough. You should have a very specific need or use case to use messages for the tasks listed in a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loose coupling doesn't mean "adding" more concrete layers to your application (a message queue etc.). If the "service" implementation classes interact with the DAO layer via interfaces (Spring DAO bean injection is a perfect use case which comes to mind), you are pretty much operating at an abstract level.

If you then swap out the concrete DAO classes injection with a messaging client which posts message to another service, your code will continue to function as it was previously without significant changes. Of course, there is always a disconnect between the blocking/non-blocking approach but nothing which a good abstraction can't solve. My suggestion would be to look into framework/libraries like Guice for creating the initial draft/refactor of your application as opposed to adding new layers. If then, at some point you feel that non-blocking DB calls are the way to go, you can implement them easily. Putting that logic upfront would just increase the technical debt.